# wpf listview populating by datatable without binding

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

i have a listview that gets data from excel file. in my case the excel files may have different formats , different headers and column numbers so it seems i cannot go for any object model binding . i want to populate the list in code. the excel data first sit in a datatable and then datatable populates listview. but since [image]there is no binding in listview i get  `System.Data.DataRowView`.

```
    var gridView = new GridView();
            this.lstv.View = gridView;

            gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
            {
                Header = "id"


            });

            gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
            {
                Header = "name"

            });

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("id");
            dt.Columns.Add("name");


            DataRow tempRow = dt.NewRow();

            tempRow[0] = "1";
            tempRow[1] = "2";


            dt.Rows.Add(tempRow);


            lstv.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;



<ListView x:Name="lstv" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="203" Margin="177,129,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="429" >

        </ListView>
```

[image]

Comment: The view doesn't know what you want to display. Try setting `DisplayMemberBinding` in the `GridViewColumn`'s

Comment: thank you @fstam this is the solution

Comment: You may want to use a `DataGrid` since it creates the `Columns` automatically based on the public `Properties` of an `Item` in the `ItemSource` (as you mentioned the Columns may vary).